# How to pass variables needed in view through redirect route in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, routes, laravel-5.5

I have modified default `auth` method in `controller` which redirects user after custom `login` to `set_password` page. The problem is I can redirect it well to the desired page but I need to simultaneously pass two dynamic variables which are returned through querying database, which I am unable to pass with redirect.

My modified `controller` method is as follows:-

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    $activated_up = User::where('id_user',Auth::user()->id_user)
                    ->where(function($query) {
                    $query->where('activated_up', '=', '1')
                    ->orWhere('activated_up', '=','0');
                })
                    ->get(['activated_up']);   
    $showuser = UserProfile::where('id_user',Auth::user()->id_user)->first();

    return redirect()->route('set_password',['activated_up' => $activated_up, 'showuser' => $showuser]); 
}
```

I know that to pass a variable to an `view`, I need to use the `compact` method like follows:-
`return view('set_password', compact('activated_up', 'showuser');` but it cant be done with redirect.

The way I have redirected means I am passing parameters to `route` in the `controller` method, but I need to pass variables to the redirected `view` instead of parameters. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried as described in the answer by [Kuldeep Mishra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50266693/how-to-pass-variables-needed-in-view-through-redirect-route-in-laravel/50266728#50266728) but could not achieve it though, anyways I found a workaround to achieve my desired output. What I did is changed my `authenticated` method to this:-

```
 protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{   
    return redirect()->route('set_password');   
}
```

I only redirected to the `set_password` route from the above method and made new method in the controller to show the view with the compacted variables like this:-

```
public function setPasswordForm(Request $request)
{
    $activated_up = User::where('id_user',Auth::user()->id_user)
                    ->where(function($query) {
                    $query->where('activated_up', '=', '1')
                    ->orWhere('activated_up', '=','0');
                })
                    ->get(['activated_up']);   
    $showuser = UserProfile::where('id_user',Auth::user()->id_user)->first();
    return view('set_password', compact('activated_up', 'showuser'));
}
```

And a small change in route `web.php` file:-

```
Route::get('/set_password', 'Controller@setPasswordForm')->name('set_password');
```

So finally I was able to redirect to desired page with the desired view loaded with dynamic variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
$activated_up = User::where('id_user',Auth::user()->id_user)
                ->where(function($query) {
                $query->where('activated_up', '=', '1')
                ->orWhere('activated_up', '=','0');
            })
                ->get(['activated_up']);   
$showuser = UserProfile::where('id_user',Auth::user()->id_user)->first();

return redirect()->route('set_password',['activated_up' => $activated_up, 'showuser' => $showuser]); 
}
```

you can use With

```
return redirect()->route('set_password')->with('data', ['some kind of 
data']);
```

in your view

```
 @if (session::has('data'))
   The data is {{ session::get('data') }}
 @endif
```

Comment: so do I need to do it like this: `return redirect()->route('set_password')->with('activated_up', 'showuser', ['$activated_up', '$showuser']);`

Comment: so do I need to do it like this: return redirect()->route('set_password')->with('activated_up'=>$activated_up,'showuser'=>$showuser); @parthu_panther

Comment: its giving this error:- `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ')'`. I guess `=>` is invalid here.

Comment: return redirect()->route('set_password')->with(['activated_up'=>$activated_up,'showuser'=>$showuser]);

Comment: parse error solved but new error is showing up:-` Class 'session' not found (View: C:\xamp\htdocs\student\resources\views\set_password.blade.php)`

Comment: use Session ;
in your controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170745/discussion-between-kuldeep-mishra-and-parthu-panther).